# Rails 4.1 / ActiveRecord / SQL ok but not returning any records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

just upgraded my Rails App from 3 to 4.1 now using jruby 1.7.18 (1.9.3p551).

There is a class called PartyMembership with two integer attributes :from, :to.

On this class, there is a scope to filter PartyMemberships by date. To get all entries where the :from, :to matches.

```
scope :at_date, lambda { |date| base.where(base.condition_for_date(date)) }
```

The following method generates the required sql query:

```
def condition_for_date(date)
      ["(#{table_name}.from IS NULL OR #{table_name}.from <= ?) AND (#{table_name}.to IS NULL OR #{table_name}.to >= ?)", date, date]
end
```

While date is a combination of year and month as integer. (e.g. 201101)

The problem now is that when there is no :to specified, ActiveRecord doesn't return any entries. When I execute the generated statement directly on the mysql console, using the same database, there are entries returned.

```
SELECT `party_memberships`.* FROM `party_memberships`  
WHERE `party_memberships`.`candidate_id` = 26353238 
AND (
  (party_memberships.from IS NULL 
   OR party_memberships.from <= 201002
  ) 
 AND (
   party_memberships.to IS NULL 
   OR party_memberships.to >= 201002)
 )  
 ORDER BY `party_memberships`.`from` ASC, 
 `party_memberships`.`from` DESC
```

When I try to execute the SQL on the rails console, there are also no entries returned.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query)
```

what reason could prevent ActiveRecord to get the correct result back ?

EDIT:

there was a problem with serializing. When the date was nil, it stored 0 instead of NULL in the db. In rails, all database actions are running inside a transaction which is rollbacked after every test. so it's not possible to see any changes on the database from the mysql console. That's why the created sql statement returned a result when I executed it on the mysql console.

Comment: what do the logs say when you execute that query?

Comment: in the log there is the above sql statement

Comment: I don't think MySQL will interpret dates in the form you have described correctly, why not use `DateTime` or `Date`?

Comment: the date convertion to integer is handled in the model class. :from and :to attributes are integer columns in the table

Comment: The generated SQL doesn't seem to match your code - where do the `OR 0` come from (although I suppose they are harmless)?  Also, where is `order` in your code?  It seems very strange to `ORDER BY` the same attribute in both directions.

Comment: the order seems strange, indeed. Tough it seems to work. When I execute the generated SQL statement on the mysql console, the expected records are returned.